# how to add multiple threads to this piece of code in matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab, multiprocessing, multicore

```
%clear all
%clc
%read and make directory
codePath = 'C:/test/';
inputPath = 'C:/test/';
outputPath = [codePath, 'splitted.frames/']
fileListName = 'fileList.out';
ip = fopen([codePath,fileListName],'rt');          % 'rt' means read text
if (ip < 0)
    error('could not open file');   % just abort if error
end;
s = fgetl(ip);                      % get a line
tic

   temp = findstr(s, '.');

   s(1:temp-1)
   %extract frame
    cd C:/Test/ffmpeg-0.5
    cmd = ['ffmpeg -i ', inputPath, s(1:temp-1), '.mp4 ', '-r 1 ', outputPath , s(1:temp-1),  '/frame%d.jpeg'];  
      dos(cmd); 


cd([codePath]);

toc
```

It provides me the elapsed time. I need to run it over multiple threads, where do I have to modify code.

Comment: Do you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Comment: This code does a single thing, what part do you want to paralelize?

Comment: it have parallel computing toolbox. I want to paralelize video frame extraction process.